# How to design a software to adapt new module handler

Tags: .net, wcf, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

I'm working on a software that displays the data from WCF services.
The WCF services are in my client's servers, I don't have permission to modify them.

My clients are having 3 applications, called: App1, App2, App3.
My responsibility is writing an application to collect the information from running application and then call a specific WCF service to get the data for displaying.

e.g: App1 is running and the user1's information is displaying on the Form1, the my application will collect the user1_id, user1_name the call Service.GetUserAlerts1(user1_id, user1_name) --> return List

App2 is running and user2's information is on the the Form2 (the Form2 is different from the Form1) --> my application will collect the user2_pin, user2_postcode, user2_idnumber then call the service Service.GetUserAlerts2(user2_pin, user2_postcode, user2_idnumber) --> return List

So I need to design my application to adapt a new App4 without any code modification. I'm thinking about using IoC pattern but I don't really know how to solve this problem.

Any ideas on that?

Thanks a lot.

Phuc

Comment: Anyone knows about MEF Framework from Microsoft?

Comment: It's not clear from your post if it's possible to have common interface for all Apps. e.g. they both supply the same data, but have different contracts. If yes you can have common logic which will consume data from each App, but load client for each application using MEF.

Comment: Yes, I think so, could you tell me some topics about using MEF?

Comment: Here is good guideline http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291628.aspx